# Too many files open error on app using Kafka

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm building an app using Kafka and Spark Streaming. Input data comes from a third part streaming and it's published on a kafka topic. This code shows the Stream Proxy module: it's the way I get the results from the streaming and how I send them to KafkaPublisher (it's shown just a sketch):

```
def on_result_response(self,*args):
    self.kafkaPublisher.pushMessage(str(args[0]))
```

The KafkaPublisher is realized with these two methods:

```
class KafkaPublisher:

def __init__(self,address,port,topic):
    self.kafka = KafkaClient(str(address)+":"+str(port))
    self.producer = SimpleProducer(self.kafka)
    self.topic=topic



def pushMessage(self,message):
    self.producer.send_messages(self.topic, message)
    self.producer = SimpleProducer(self.kafka, async=True)
```

And the app is launched by this main:

```
from StreamProxy import StreamProxy


streamProxy=StreamProxy("localhost",9092,"task1")
streamProxy.getStreaming(20)  #seconds of streaming
```

After some batch processing (10 seconds more or less) it's launched the following **exceptions**:

> Exception in thread Thread-2354:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/producer/base.py", line 164, in _send_upstream
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 649, in send_produce_request
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 253, in _send_broker_aware_request
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 74, in _get_conn
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 236, in connect
>     error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
>
> Exception in thread Thread-2355:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/producer/base.py", line 164, in _send_upstream
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 649, in send_produce_request
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 253, in _send_broker_aware_request
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client.py", line 74, in _get_conn
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 236, in connect
>     error: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Please note that there are many different exceptions with the same message and surely the problem is publisher-side.

Comment: is `StreamProxy` something you wrote? If so can you link the source code to `getStreaming`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the row:

```
self.producer = SimpleProducer(self.kafka, async=True)
```

Comment: @hyruma92 that would be a better answer if you could explain the problem in the code and what the fix does. Thanks

Comment: because you create a new producer for every message when using the one created on init is sufficient